# Creating a tabcontrol in MVVM from a central datasource

Tags: wpf, mvvm, synchronization, tabcontrol

I am new to MVVM, and I am trying to implement a simple application, following the pattern.

For simplicity, I am breaking the problem down to it's simplest form. If I manage to get this to work, I will have little trouble getting the application made.

The simple application consists of a tabcontrol. It is important that both tabs have their own ViewModel. However, they will get most of their data from the same source. The main issue is to get the second tab to know that the first have initiated a change on the datasource.

So, for simplicity, let's just say that the model is holding a single integer. This integer needs initially to be set to 1.

The first tab is holding a textblock and a button. The text of the textblock is bound to the integer in the datamodel. Upon pressing the button, the integer in the moddel should be incremented with 1.

The second tab holds only a textblock, also bound to the integer in the datamodel. The challenge is to get this textblock to update along with the first textblock, but still being it's own viewmodel.

I need somewhere central to store the values of the model, and in some way, let the viewmodels know that they have been updated, so their properties can be updated, and the Views therefore get's updated accordingly.

Can someone explain in as much detail as possible how this is done? I have tried a billion different ways, but I am not getting it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I have your question down right:

- You have a data source (your model).
- You have 2 view models.
- View model 1 changes data in the model.
- View model 2 needs to update with changes in the model.

If that all sounds right, here's one solution:

Have your model implement INotifyPropertyChanged. When the integer changes, raise the PropertyChanged event. In view model 2, listen for the model's PropertyChanged event. When it occurs, raise view model 2's property changed event, and its UI will get updated automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You got the question right, and it sounds like an interesting approach - I will try it first thing tonight. I will return with information if it solved my problem or not :)

Comment: There is another approach using the messenger/mediator pattern. But this seems like the *right* approach.

Comment: Thanks - I have gotten it to work now. thanks to all contributors.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea in which scenario you want to do that.
But a solution that crosses my mind is to have a "parent" ViewModel that holds instances of the two tab ViewModels.

e.g.

```
public class ParentViewModel{

   private Tab1ViewModel viewModel1;
   private Tab2ViewModel viewModel2;
}
```

Then the ParentViewModel can subscribe to the INotifyPropertyChanged event of the ViewModel1 and set the value on the ViewModel2.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer :) The scenario is where I have a collection of data stored, and my different tabs shows different things, which are all calculated by their respective viewmodels to be presented in a certain way. The bread and butter is that changing something on tab X, will affect the collection of Data, and therefore all the tabs should automatically have their properties updated. But I cannot even get the second tab react to the simplified example I gave. I will try to look into your suggestion, but if my clarifucation gave you a new idea, I would love to hear from you again :)

Comment: Reading my comment, I wasn't quite clear. The data collection of all the tabs is the same, but they are all displaying them differntly, based on various methods implemented on the various viewmodels. C command on tab 1 might change some of the data, which would mean that all other tabs should get updated :)

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implemented something similar to this. It was for implementing a wizard, consisting of:

- 7 Views
- 8 View models
- 1 Model

The main ViewModel created the Model and passed this on to all the other view models through their constructors.

In your scenario you could have a main ViewModel with an ObservableCollection of ViewModels. Each of these VM's would have the same instance of the model as their data source.

As previously mentioned, implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the model and bind the views directly to the model through a property on the ViewModel. I found this diagram very useful : http://karlshifflett.files.wordpress.com/2009/01/wpflobmvvm1.png